# gap in layout due to display:table

Tags: html, css

i have a difficulty and its about `display:table` , i was  working on a one page website and i have a navbar and a `.product` section below it , now inside `.product` the section , i have a carousel and i want the carousel centered vertically and so i have used the following technique ::

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .products {
        height: 100%;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .products .carousel-wrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/89Lfekka/8/)**

unfortunatly there is a but gap between the `.product` section and the `nav` element , both sibling elements , if i add `display:block` to the products section than my layout gets screwed , but th gap is gone , so i need to stick to `table` . why is the gap there i have checked for margin and padding , but there is none , so i see nothing obvious for the gap to be there , but its still there .

can somebody tell me why i am getting this huge gap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an `margin-bottom: 20px;` at your .navbar class

and you have 2 spans with an height of 50 px

thats your gap in the fiddle

you fiddle forked: http://jsfiddle.net/ej8dtd1z/

Answer (score 1):

You gap is due to your 2 empty `<span>` and your css rule `nav span` have that: `min-height: 50px !important;`

To fix that, you can:

- Remove the `<span>`

AND/OR

- Add a class to your menu `<span>` to apply your css rule just on the correct ones

Answer (score 1):

I built a **grid system** base on `display:table` use this following code:

```
.products {
  position: relative;/*you wont need this one*/
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.products > * {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.youritems { 
  vertical-align: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

first you build a table then the element inside with `.youritems` css will be easy to move with `text-align` and `vertical-align`

Comment: awesome , but i bet it was't responsive . :D but thats a very good idea .

Comment: it was responsive , in fact it was 3 grid system in one, :P, thanks

Comment: would love to see a dmo really , if you have one !